# How do i show auto complete html file in VScode?

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

Please consider I'm not good at english because I'm Korean.

This picture show the auto completed html file in Intellij.

That file was created by spring boot(start.spring.io).

How do i this in VScode?

[image]

Comment: snippets or Emmet

Answer (score 1):

Create a new File  in VScode something like "test.html"

Then type "!" into the file and press enter.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Good night!(Korea is now 11:00PM lol)